# порой/изредка/время от времени

Tags: значения

Есть ли существенная разница в употреблении следующих слов и выражений -- '*порой*', '*изредка*' и '*время от времени*'? То есть, можно ли употреблять их как синонимы, или мне надо относиться к каждому по-разному?

Answer (score 5):

Все эти слова означают то же, что и **иногда** (sometimes), но при этом у каждого из них есть свои особенности.

- *изредка* = иногда + (очень) редко
- *время от времени* = иногда + (до некоторой степени) регулярно
- *порой* = иногда + неожиданно, нерегулярно

Примеры:

> Как взор его был быстр и нежен,
>   Стыдлив и дерзок, а *порой*
>   Блистал послушною слезой!
>   (А.С. Пушкин "Евгений Онегин")
>
> Рогожин *изредка* и *вдруг* начинал *иногда* бормотать, громко, резко и бессвязно; начинал вскрикивать и смеяться...
>   (Ф.М. Достоевский "Идиот")

Comment: Give us some examples please. I'm especially interested in the word "порой".

Comment: @VCH250 Порой возникает желание выпить водки. Порой сквозь тучи выглянет луна. А мне порой так не хватает просто теплоты... Порой люди, которые якобы ничего из себя не представляют, совершают удивительные вещи.

Comment: @VCH250 Никто не запрещает вам изредка вспоминать прошлое, но, пожалуйста, перестаньте им жить. Изредка в жизни, если очень повезет, в самый тяжелый момент встречаешь такого человека, который спасает твою душу. Изредка можно видеть над цветами проворный шмелей.

Comment: @VCH250 Почему общий баланс моего счета время от времени меняется? Время от времени нам встречаются нежные люди. Мы время от времени сталкиваемся с кадровыми проблемами. Подборка фильмов, которые я с удовольствием пересматриваю время от времени.

Comment: @VCH250 OK, added.

Comment: @ user4419802 Is it possible that "порой" is actually "пора" but in the instrumental case?

Comment: @VCH250 Yes, sure. "И вы, красотки молодые,//Которых _позднею порой_//Уносят дрожки удалые//По петербургской мостовой..."